# Minimum of an apparently harmless function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I would like to prove that the minimum of the function

$$
f(x,y):=\frac{(1-\cos(\pi x))(1-\cos (\pi y))\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x^2 y^2 \sqrt{(1-\cos(\pi x))(2+\cos(\pi y))+(2+\cos(\pi x))(1-\cos(\pi y))}}
$$

over the domain $[0,1]^2$ is $2\sqrt{2}$. Looking at the 2D plot of the function

[image: Plot of f]

one immediately notices that the minimum is $f(1,1) = 2\sqrt{2}$. However, I can't figure out how to prove this in a rigorous way, even if the expression of $f$ seems to have a nice, "quasi-separable" structure...

Any suggestion is welcomed!

Comment: Why you just don't do the following:  find extremum inside the area if any. Then look for minimum on the bound - square. Here you function reduces to 4 one-dimensional functions. You look for extremums there, compare in with their boundaries - 4 points and finally have your desired 1,1 point?

Comment: Just out of curiosity... how did you arrive at this???

Comment: @hvedrung looking for stationary points inside the area is not such an easy task unfortunately... the gradient of $f$ is a monster! :D

Comment: @AloizioMacedo this should be the last step of a proof regarding the inf-sup condition of a particular Petrov-Galerkin method I am working on..

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that almost works. I haven't been able to find a nice argument to establish the inequality $(\spadesuit)$ below, but verifying the inequality using the code

```
Reduce[(1 - Cos[Pi*x])^2 - (2 + Cos[Pi*x])*(8 x^4 - 4 x^8) > 0 && 0 < x < 1, x]
```

in Mathematica gives me the result

```
0 < x < 1
```

so I am almost certain the inequality is true. (I get a warning that numeric integration is being used to verify the completeness of the solution set.) If I find an appropriate argument, I'll edit the post.

---

Since $f$ is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, it suffices to show that $f(x,y)\geq 2\sqrt2$ holds for all $0<x<y<1$. (For points on the boundary, the inequality follows by continuity.)

Define $\phi:(0,1)\to(0,2)$ by $$\phi(x)=1-\cos\pi x.$$ Note that this is an increasing bijective function. For all $x\in(0,1)$ we have $$\phi(x)\geq2x^2,\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$ as can be easily seen using elementary calculus.

To avoid dealing with square roots, we will analyse the square of your function: $$f(x,y)^2=\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^4y^4}\frac{\phi(x)^2\phi(y)^2}{\phi(x)(3-\phi(y))+\phi(y)(3-\phi(x))}.$$ Since $\phi$ is strictly increasing and $x<y$, we have: $$\phi(x)(3-\phi(y))+\phi(y)(3-\phi(x))\leq2\phi(y)(3-\phi(x)).$$ Therefore, $$f(x,y)^2\geq\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^4y^4}\frac{\phi(x)^2\phi(y)^2}{2\phi(y)(3-\phi(x))}\geq\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^4y^2}\frac{\phi(x)^2}{3-\phi(x)}.\tag{$\ast$}$$ where in the second step we have cancelled one of the $\phi(y)$ and used $(\clubsuit)$ to get rid of the other one.

According to Mathematica, the following inequality is true for $x\in(0,1)$: $$\frac{\phi(x)^2}{3-\phi(x)}\geq8x^4-4x^8.\tag{$\spadesuit$}$$
Using this in $(\ast)$ and cancelling $x^4$, we immediately have: $$f(x,y)^2\geq\frac{(8-4x^4)(x^2+y^2)}{y^2}.$$ It remains to show that this last expression is bounded below by $8$, or equivalently: $$(8-4x^4)(x^2+y^2)\geq 8y^2.$$ But this is true, since $$(8-4x^4)(x^2+y^2)-8y^2=4x^2 (2-x^2(x^2+y^2))\geq0$$ obviously holds for $0<x<y<1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Anyway, (♠) doesn't seem really trivial to prove, but I'll try to work on it!

Comment: @Paglia: Indeed, it looks like a harmless calculus exercise, but when you try to prove it, it's not =) I'll let you know if I come up with something.

Comment: Exactly, when I found this function during my research I thought exactly the same "ok, fine, this is just a calculus exercise!" but it was definitely not! :D

Answer (score -1):

It is enough to show that both ((x^2 + y^2)^1/2 )/ (x^2 y^2) and the other part

have minimum at (1,1) :

For ((x^2 + y^2)^1/2 )/ (x^2 y^2) the minimum happens at (x,y)=(1,1) and the

minimum is (2^1/2)

For the other part:

Put  1-cosx = A , a-cosx = B

0 < A < = 2 , 0 < B < = 2

Find the minimum point for AB / ((A)(3-B)+(3-A)(B))^1/2  when  0 < A <= 2 , 0 < B < = 2

It happens at (A,B)=(2,2) which means (x,y)=(1,1). The minimum of this is 2.

So the minimum of f(x,y) happens at (x,y)=(1,1) and this is 2(2^1/2)

Comment: Unfortunately this argument does not work... the minimum of $AB / \sqrt{A(3-B) + (3-A) B}$ in $[0,2]^2$ is $0$ and it is realized in $(A,B)=(0,0)$...